# How to get the data file in SPSS in which the variables used are indicated?

Tags: cluster-analysis, spss, hierarchical-clustering

I have the dataset and used SPSS to perform cluster analysis. Now in order to know which stage and step represents what variable, I need to have the data file in which it is indicated which variables were used to implement the cluster analysis. I've saved the cluster solution but it did not help. Which actions or steps should be performed to get the needed data file for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to get the specifications for the clustering, the Viewer file in which it was generated will have the syntax in the log blocks.  You can also look at the journal file, which normally contains all the syntax that has been run.  To find the file, look at Edit > Options > Files.

If you are looking for more than that, please clarify the question.